# Edit Html in Real time and get full source code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried many wsiwyg editor to edit my .html file in realtime most of them ignores the `<html>` tag and also formats my code(I dont want because I have minified my html)

So I am planning to create my own version of boormaklet to do this. so basically I want to edit the webpage live and get the code.I used following code.

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true';  
document.designMode='on'; 
void 0;
```

And then I want to get full page source , so I tried below, its ignoring the edited text and also ignoring `<html>` tag

```
$( 'html' ).html().toString();
```

So How to get the full source code without modifying the code ,and with `<html>` tag

Comment: First, tool recommendation is off-topic being primarily opinion-based, second, provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue described.

Comment: Did you know editing HTML or CSS in Google Chrome will give you a live preview, and you can save your changes to local files? Learn more at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: @LGSon : please see the edit , remove the upvote

Comment: Have you tried something like http://jsfiddle.net? I'm not really sure what you are looking for

Comment: I want to edit it realtime on chrome by clicking on the output , jsfiddle will allow only code edit , I can do that with me cpanel editor itself.

Answer (score 4):

Try $('html').get(0).outerHTML;It should provide you the full code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: hi , chrome is adding some unwanted codes in header style type="text/css">@font-face {font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('chrome-extension://gkompgmhhdflejbdgfjlmipjpjfdoclm/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:ur

Comment: The above code might be due to some inline css codes in your document. Try removing them

Comment: You can try "new  XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)" but I think it will give you the same result.